# Execute loop based on a list - obtain result for each page (subpage)

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to obtain the number of pages for each url from a list of urls. My code works as long as I have only one url, however as soon as I try it with a list of urls I only get the rest from one url. Guess the problem is related to my loop. given that I am new to python and beautifoul soup I dont manage to spot the mistake myself.

```
base_url = 'https://www.holidaycheck.de'
main_page = 'https://www.holidaycheck.de/dh/hotels-tunesien/e10cef63-45d4-3511-92f1-43df5cbd9fe1?p={}'
urls=[]

##Change URL into object (soup)
r = requests.get(main_page.format(0))  
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html5lib")

#get max page number
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
data = soup.find_all('a', {'class':'link'})

res = []
for i in data:
    res.append(i.text) #writing each value to res list

res_int = []
for i in res:
    try:
        res_int.append(int(i))
    except:
        print("current value is not a number")
last_page=max(res_int)
#print(last_page)


for i in range (1,last_page):
    page = main_page.format(i)
    for link in soup.find_all('div', {'class':'hotel-reviews-bar'}):
       urls = base_url + link.find('a').get('href')+"/-/p/{}"
       print(urls)
```

So far, everything works, I obtain the max page number and get all the urls from each page. The problem lies in the code below (I believe):

```
for url in urls: #to loop through the list of urls
    r = requests.get(url.format(0)) 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    daten = soup.find_all('a', {'class':'link'})

    tes = []
    for z in daten:
        tes.append(z.text) #writing each value to res list
       print(tes)

    tes_int = []
    for z in tes:
        try:
            tes_int.append(int(z))
        except:
            print("current value is not a number")
    anzahl=max(tes_int)
    print(anzahl)
```

I am trying to apply the same concept as in the code above for each url from the list urls- but instead of obtaining the max page number for each url I obtain 241 every time, as if I am caught in a loop...

Any thoughts on that? Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Check the value of `urls` before the `for url in urls:` loop, I think you'll be surprised.

Comment: you didn't define `base_url`

Comment: also fix your indentation in 2nd code block

Comment: @Błotosmętek I checked the Urls they look fine. I also randomly opened links form the list and they worked. Should that not be the case?

Comment: No, you didn't. Your variable `urls` at the beginning of the loop contains **one** URL. See Dmitriy Fialkovkiy's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're *equating* `urls` to last link generated by loop.
To build valid list of urls you need to replace `=` on `append()`:

```
urls = []
for i in range (1,last_page):
    page = main_page.format(i)
    r = requests.get(page) #these 2 rows added
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml') #these 2 rows added
    for link in soup.find_all('div', {'class':'hotel-reviews-bar'}):
        try:
            urls.append(base_url + link.find('a').get('href')+"/-/p/{}")
        except:
            print('no link available', i)
print(urls)
```

**EDIT:** okay, as far as I see you have *several* issues in your code. along with my initial fix I'm outlining my vision and understanding of how your code desired to work:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
base_url = 'https://www.holidaycheck.de'
main_page = 'https://www.holidaycheck.de/dh/hotels-tunesien/e10cef63-45d4-3511-92f1-43df5cbd9fe1?p={}'

##Change URL into object (soup)
r = requests.get(main_page.format(0))  
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html5lib")

#get max page number
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
data = soup.find_all('a', {'class':'link'})

res = []
for i in data:
    res.append(i.text) #writing each value to res list

res_int = []
for i in res:
    try:
        res_int.append(int(i))
    except:
        print("current value is not a number")
last_page=max(res_int)
#print(last_page)


urls = []
for i in range (1,last_page):
    page = main_page.format(i)
    r = requests.get(page) #these 2 rows added
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml') #these 2 rows added
    for link in soup.find_all('div', {'class':'hotel-reviews-bar'}):
        try: #also adding try-except for escaping broken/unavailable links
            urls.append(base_url + link.find('a').get('href')+"/-/p/{}")
        except:
            print('no link available', i)

urls = list(set(urls)) #check and drop duplicated in links list

for url in urls: #to loop through the list of urls
    try:
        r = requests.get(url.format(0))
        print(url.format(0))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
        daten = soup.find_all('a', {'class':'link'})
    except:
        print('broken link')

    tes = []
    for z in daten:
        tes.append(z.text) #writing each value to res list
#    print(tes)

    tes_int = []
    for z in tes:
        try:
            tes_int.append(int(z))
        except:
            print("current value is not a number")
    try:
        anzahl=max(tes_int)
        print(anzahl)
    except:
        print('maximum cannot be calculated')
```

Comment: Don't forget to initialize `urls`. Even better, replace the `for` loop with a list comprehension.

Comment: `urls` are initialized in the question code above, but it makes sense to add it here. added `urls`.

Comment: Ok, I fixed my code based on @DmitriyFialkovskiy comments but still dont get the max page number for the subpage?What do you mean by replace the for loop with a list comprehension? Writing it all in one nested line?

Comment: btw, @Nadine, I'm not 100% sure of proper indentation, because you still didn't fix it in your question

Comment: @DmitriyFialkovskiy what do you mean by indentation?Arrangement of the different code lines? Honestly, this so far this is mainly based on fixing error messages (when I removed / added spaces they disappeared). I am still learning with help of tutorial but I guess this code is way too advanced (I am discovering new things to consider everyday)

Comment: to be short - proper spacing in loops in your case.
https://www.quora.com/What-does-indentation-mean-in-python

Comment: Ok I see. What do you think needs to be adjusted in the second block? Remove the space between print(tes) and test_int[]?

Comment: @Nadine, I've added an edit to your question with indentation fix.

Comment: ok saw what you mean. Still surprised that the code still worked. Thanks a lot again for your help!

Comment: @DmitriyFialkovskiy Sorry for bringing this up again, but I just realized that I only get the Urls from the first page. I  get each URL 68 times....thought this was fixed with the urls.append but no

Comment: @Nadine, yes, this happened because you didn't reassign `soup` for parsing. And I didn't notice it initially either. Let me add this part in solution.

Comment: @DmitriyFialkovskiy 
line 67, in <module> anzahl=max(tes_int)
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence

Comment: btw, you need maximum from ALL the pages? if yes, then my current fix should be correct

Comment: @DmitriyFialkovskiy No, I need the max for each url,not the overall max across all urls.
so I need to change the indentation or?

Comment: @DmitriyFialkovskiy tried the code. I get 281 urls now, however the total number of urls I should get is 827

Comment: right, you get 281 urls because other urls aren't available. 
 `link.find('a').get('href')` in respective loop gives error in some cases, that's why I put `try-except` there. If you need `max` for each url, then `print(anzahl)` should be inside loop, I'll put it back. But there also should be `try-except` because sometimes `tes_int` is empty.

Comment: you can also manually explore pages, on which `link.find('a').get('href')` is not finding anything and/or making error, maybe there's another tag/attribute from which you could collect urls.

Comment: Will do that. One final question, if I want to save the results to an excel file column A url, column B max number of pages. I now added 
    from openpyxl import Workbook
    from openpyxl import load_workbook

    wb = Workbook()
    ws = wb.active

above the baseline command and:
    ws.append([url,anzahl])
    wb.save("hotels.xlsx")

under the last line of code, but I keep getting only one row (one url) does that mean I am caught in a loop again?@DmitriyFialkovskiy

Comment: sorry, can't help here right away, I didn't use this library, always used `pandas` for such purposes=)

Comment: @DmitriyFialkovskiy ok too bad. I works with the good where I only get the urls form the first page. Can you adjust the code that I see the page max page per url so that I can just copy it from the result screen. Right now I only the the max page for the last url and i dont manage to switch it so that I see all

Comment: please check now